# Netty Framework: When is channelOpen called?

Tags: netty

According to the Netty guide: http://static.netty.io/3.5/guide/#start.12

> *To keep track of open sockets, you need to modify the
>   TimeServerHandler to add a new open Channel to the global
>   ChannelGroup, TimeServer.allChannels:*

```java
  @Override
  public void channelOpen(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
        TimeServer.allChannels.add(e.getChannel());
  }
```

I implemented `channelOpen` on my business logic handler. I don't see it called when a new client makes a connection. Can anyone say in detail when `channelOpen` is called?

Also, can I write an upstream handler to be inserted **before** the `ExecutionHandler` and expect `channelOpen` to be called at the appropriate time, or does one *have to* implement `channelOpen` on the business logic handler?

I'd like to be able to implement `channelOpen` separately from the business logic handler if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The events comes in, in this order:

channelOpen(..), channelBound(..), channelConnected(..)

...

cannelDisconnected(..), channelUnbound(..), channelClosed(..)

So channelOpen(..) should be called as first thing when a client connects..